# Internet keeps connecting and disconnecting

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, drivers, internet

I have a PC running 32bit Windows 7 Professional.
My wireless internet card is Edimax EW-7128G, it is inside my computer case and it is connected to an antenna.

My problem is:
I have a wireless connection to my router, the signal is fine and it's not slow or anything, but it just keeps disconnecting every 30 seconds or so, then connects back, then it disconnects, then connects back and so on.

This is new - it only started about a week ago, everything worked just fine until then.

I know it's not a problem with the router because:
Other computers can connect to it easily and they work just fine, no disconnections (My phone too).

I know it's not a problem with the computer or the wireless card itself because:
I have Ubuntu installed side-by-side with my Windows, and when I switch to Ubuntu the internet works great.

This caused me to think it's probably a problem with the wireless card drivers installed on windows (Ubuntu auto-installed them, I installed them manually on windows):
I tried uninstalling them, and then installing them back again, sadly that didn't help.

I'm kind of lost here - can anyone think of anything else I should try?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you said this is a recent issue with equipment which worked before, here are things I would do first.

**System Changes -** Think about what has recently changed. Has there been a Windows Update recently when you started noticing the problem? You can use `System Restore` back to a date you know when it was working in order to resolve the issue.

**Drivers -**
Make sure all Windows updates installed. Then make sure you have the latest [Windows drivers](http://www.edimax.com/en/support_detail.php?pd_id=1&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=) for the wireless card from the manufacturer (a lot of times the drivers that come with the card are outdated by the time it product reaches the end consumer).

**Viruses / Malware -** Scan your computer for viruses and malware. If you need help with that, here is a great resource - [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/a/512901/97028)

**Card Failure -** Lastly, there is a possibility the wireless card could have just failed altogether. Follow any troubleshooting the manufacture recommends.

Comment: As I said I already downloaded brand new drivers from the Edimax website and reinstalled them.
I will try installing Windows updates.
Card Failure is not the problem - as I said the internet works great when I boot to Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried installing updates, installing new anti virus software and running some scans - that didn't help. Though I did solve the problem by using an Edimax USB dongle that acts like a network card and an antenna, windows seems to get along with this one and I don't get disconnects anymore.

Comment: Yes, you are right about it not being a card failure. As I was getting to the end of my answer thought process, I had forgotten you were successfully using it with Ubuntu. Glad you found a work around. Did you happen to try system restore?

Comment: No, no system restore, never done that before and I'm not very familiar with how it works. Also, I can't recall exactly when the problem started so I don't know what point to restore to.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the things suggested but non of them worked.

What did work was not actually a full solution, but using an Edimax USB dongle that acts like an antenna and a network card (Edimax EW-7711UMn) allows me to connect to the internet without any disconnections, everything works smooth now.

The only explanation I see for the problem is that Windows and my network card just don't get along anymore - must be some problem with the drivers.